# Python starts in separate command line window

Tags: python, cmd

When I try to start Python (any version) from CMD (by simply typing "python" and pressing Enter to start the interpreter), nothing happens (or, more likely, the interpreter opens and closes in a new window in just milliseconds). This problem influences every IDE I try to use. For example, Sublime text does not show the output anymore. PyCharm, on the other hand, opens an empty interpreter after every action, every key-press, on start-up, on save/load.

This influences my work process quite a lot and I can't seem to find a solution. Neither I know how, why or when it's began to behave like this.

I am uncertain whether this is Python or CMD related, because it happens for every Python version.

Comment: just reinstall python.

Comment: @MK. that was too obvious not to try it before asking... If I said it happens with every version, it could mean I've tried more than I actually use. Not even my portable versions work on my PC, although they work on others.

Comment: Complete shot in the dark, but type `where python` on the CMD prompt in case your path contains something else named `python`. Alternately: What happens if you type the full path to the python executable?

Comment: @alexis If I open CMD in the same folder as the executable, and the type "python", same thing, nothing happens. If I type it with ".exe", whether it is full or relative path, it launches the interpreter in a separate window.
By the way, calling .py files in CMD has no effect as well.

Comment: About the where command, there are no other places I have a python.exe in %path%.

Comment: install process monitor https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx and use it to see which executable actually runs and which files are accessed when you run python.

Comment: @MK. Thank you, that actually helped a lot. The problem was the AVG TuneUp, that was recently installed by someone. Although tweaks where not done via this program at all, it was actively trying to block any python process. Uninstalling it has solved the problem. Thank you again.

Comment: 99% of time weird ass problems on Windows are caused by the anvirus software.  Curiously, I've never seen antivirus actually stop a virus or malware.  It is almost as weird as node.js.

Comment: @MK. I also don't have an antivirus as I also think that they are useless and usually just troublemakers. But the weird part is that TuneUp is not even an antivirus, it's some kind of "Boost your System" software you'd usually see on ads. I still can't understand why it'd block one particular *.exe. Moreover, I've looked through it's options/features, there is no single reference of Python.